# Получить данные по id и показать на странице php

Tags: php

как я могу получить данные по id и показать на странице php?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>xxx</title>
</head>
<body>    
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'big-torrent';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysql_select_db("big-torrent");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM games";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

?>
<ul id="ulform"><li id="liform">
<div class="container" align="center">
  <img src="<?php echo $row['full_path'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text"><?php echo "<a href='".$row['link']."' id='atext'>".$row['name'] .'<br>'. ' - скачат - ' . $row['size']  . "</a>";?></div>
  </div>
  <div align="center" id="textname">
  <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
  </div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
<?php
 }
 mysql_close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: От куда данные  вы хотите получить? Не много конкретики и примера кода можно?

Comment: Добавьте ваш код.

Comment: Я хочу создать сайт, у меня на главном странице есть картинки игр и у них есть id, и я хочу создать страницу где менялись данные зависимое от id?

Comment: Получайте id из массива $_GET или $_POST, а id передавайте в POST или GET запросе с помощью тела запроса в первом случае или с помощью параметров во втором случае. Причем у вас еще ошибка, connect через mysqli, а функции используются mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала советую привести в порядок код и отделить модель от представления, иначе при росте количества кода запутаетесь в нем.

Про конкретно ваш вопрос, если речь про этот участок кода:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM games";
```

то здесь делается простой запрос с WHERE:

```
"SELECT * FROM games WHERE id='".$id."' LIMIT 1;"
```

P.S. Как верно заметил @Firepro, в переменную $id должны поступать безопасные и предварительно отформатированные данные.

Comment: За такую конкатенацию переменной id в строку запроса к базе данных где-то говорит 'спасибо' начинающий хакер :) Минусну Вас за несоблюдение безопасности подготовки запросов, пока не исправите ответ.

Comment: @Firepro обоснуйте свое предположение. чем вам не угодила конкатенация в моем примере? никто не говорил, что переменная $id поступает в запрос в сыром виде. она должна фильтроваться (спецсимволы экранируются) и проверяться на соответствие типу данных (например, is_numeric и т.д.).

Comment: Это как минимум следовало бы добавить в ответ, чтобы огородить новичков от мыслей конкатенировать сырую переменную. А в идеале было бы направить пользователя на верный путь и предложить пользоваться встроенными подготовленными запросами (id = ?), вместо предложенной конкатенации в целях повышения безопасности и уменьшения вероятности ошибки безопасности из-за человеческого фактора

Comment: @Firepro да, это имеет смысл дополнить в моем ответе (про безопасность поступающих данных). что касается самого запроса - конечно, можно использовать CONCAT, подготовленные выражения, но на практике это только усложняет код без какой-либо пользы (конечно, если поступающие переменные уже были соответствующим образом проверены и отформатированы).

Comment: @Firepro к тому же вопросы сетевой безопасности в этом примере будут явно избыточны (это огромная тема, которую не объяснить за 5 минут). автор спросил про обычный WHERE-запрос, а вы его уже в подготовленные выражения кидаете)))

Comment: Поставил плюс за полный ответ по построению запроса) Подготовленные выражения все же несут меньше головной боли, чем например ORM))